# How can I change the package directory

Tags: julia

I am using a university server to run some julia files. The contents of the C:/ drive are deleted every evening so that includes any packages I may have downloaded.

```
(@v1.9) pkg> st

Status `C:\Users\[name]\.julia\environments\v1.9\Project.toml`
```

The above toml file is reset to empty every day.

I do have access to a different H:/ drive that holds all the packages I need but I have been unable to change the directory to H:\julia\registries.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried the `cd` command and the `--project` command but neither resulted into getting the status of the package directory to change to the one I wanted.

Comment: Try setting the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`. The relevant manual link is https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_DEPOT_PATH

Comment: Can you please provide a way to reproduce your error. This will allow the community to give an accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `--project` command line argument to change the default package environment. However, notice that the `~/.julia` directory also contains other data than the package environment (see [`DEPOT_PATH`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/constants/#Base.DEPOT_PATH)). Since, in your case, all this data is deleted periodically, it is a better idea to direct Julia to use another directory in place of `~/.julia`, rather than just changing the package environment.

You can use another directory, say `H:\julia-env-v1.9`, in place of `~/julia` by setting the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` environment variable to `H:\julia-env-v1.9`. You should also create the directory `H:\julia-env-v1.9`.

When you start Julia, the depot directory in your persistent drive will be used.

```
$ julia
(@v1.9) pkg> st
  Installing known registries into `H:\julia-env-v1.9`
      Status `H:\julia-env-v1.9\environments\v1.9\Project.toml` (empty project)
```